# Why are the functions that result from an iterated integral in the Fubini Theorem themselves integrable?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I'm currently questioning why I can integrate the answer of an inside integral during Fubini Theorem exercises. To make myself more clear, here's an example: let's consider the double integral of the continuous function z(x,y) over a region R in the xy-plane described by $a\le{x}\le{b}$ and $h_1(x)\le{y}\le{h_2(x)}$ ($h_1$ and $h_2$ are continuous), and apply Fubini's Theorem:

$$\int\int_Rz(x,y)dydx = \int_a^b\int_{h_1(x)}^{h_2(x)}z(x,y)dydx$$

We know for sure that the first integral is valid because we said z is continuous. However, the question arises when evaluating the outside integral: how do we know that the answer to the inside integral will be integrable? I would guess that the Fubini Theorem itself possibly gives reasoning that states the answer will always be integrable; however, I do not know if that is true. I also thought maybe the answer to an integral with continuous variable bounds will always be integrable, but while I doubt that hypothesis, I currently haven't been able to come up with example functions that violate that it. So, why is the result of that integral also integrable? Thank you for any insight you have!

Comment: the converse of Fubini is not true. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1891209/converse-of-fubinis-theorem

Comment: @user29418 I don't see how the question you linked is relevant to the asked question. As I understand it the question being asked here is : Why is $x \mapsto \int_{h_1(x)}^{h_2(x)} z(x,y) dy$ an integrable function  on $[a,b]$ ?

Comment: The inner definite integral is a continuous function of $x$. Think it through.

Comment: This is a very important issue, and it definitely needs to be addressed when discussing Fubini's theorem. Now, in the case where $z$ is continuous, everything becomes much nicer, because the resulting map $x\mapsto \int_{h_1(x)}^{h_2(x)}z(x,y)\, dy$ is in fact contiunuous on $[a,b]$ (actually also uniformly continuous), and hence Riemann-integrable. In the general case where you assume $z$ is only Riemann-integrable, things become slightly more complicated, and I suggest you take a look a the proof of the theorem (eg. in Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds)

Comment: So, when assuming z is continuous, the resulting function of x is also continuous on [a,b]? Is this given in the proof from Spivak?